# I'm getting this type of screen after screen reopen in some applications in 20.04

Tags: command-line, suspend, screen, lock

when I lock or suspend and close the screen after reopen screen I'm getting this type of undefined screen in some parts of applications like vs code terminal and Viber.
Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Laptop: Hp Envy 
Ubuntu Version : 20.04 LTS

Comment: did you any extensions related to above apps?

Comment: Not exactly sure, perhaps related to this old bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300?

Comment: these apps do not have any extensions @PRATAP

Comment: I don't think these are same @pomsky